# Trying to get MEAN maps to work on windows

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-maps, npm, mean-stack

I cloned this mean map that I watched on a azure mongodb video , and I did the same steps in the readme like they did

https://github.com/scotch-io/mean-google-maps

So

```
npm install
node server.js 

// I didn't do any mongodb , as there is a config.js that is pointing at an amazon mongodb.
```

On the video they didn't do any mongodb locally

I see that in chrome console it throws an error with modernizr

```
  #!/usr/bin/env node
```

That line is red squiggly ,  it that line causing the map to not load?  Is that even going to work on a Windows 10 machine I'm running?

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with mongodb.

The problem is the Modernizr link in the *public/index.html* (line 18) points to a script which is designed to be run server side.
The shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node` indicate a javascript file that must be run with Nodejs. Your browser can't run this kind of script.

It's looks like a confusion in bower dependency management.
(I think it is generaly not a good practive to include *bower_components* directory into git repository)

Maybe you can try to fix it by replacing the link with a cdnjs version of Modernizer:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js
Or just delete the line, you use a recent Chrome browser after all...